# Hide footer with css when slide is active

Tags: jquery, html, css

Wondering how I can turn the display of my footer to none when i have a certain active container:

Example:
How would I turn the css of footer to none, when the second and third items are selected with active?

```
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item"></div>
  <div class="owl-item active"></div>
  <div class="owl-item"></div>
</div>
<footer>
  <select id="select" style="display:block"></select>
</footer>
```

I thought maybe css, though don't think this is possible?

```
.owl-stage:nth-of-type(2).owl-item.active footer select,
.owl-stage:nth-of-type(3).owl-item.active footer select {
      display: none;
    }
```

I was thinking:

```
$(".owl-stage:nth-of-type(2) .owl-item.active").?????('footer #select').css("display", "none");
```

Any ideas how I could make this work with some js?

Thanks, Barry

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be done

```
if( $('.owl-item:nth-child(2)').hasClass('active')) $('footer').find('#select').hide()
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7vqhwfsh/)

Comment: This is great, thanks! Doesn't seem to work with me? I think the problem is, the links (.active) are only getting added after the page has loaded, they are attached when certain slides are active in the carousel. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible to use bind somehow: `$('.owl-stage.eq(4).owl-item').bind('', function () {
    $('footer > select').css("display", "none");
  });`

Comment: You can try adding this script on window.load instead document.ready

Comment: can you post URL where you are actually trying

Comment: Unfortunately, everything running locally in a dev environment. Pulling my hair out trying to sort this. I was wondering if I can some how attach it to the carousel listener, if that makes sense.

Comment: Could we use this some how? [Owl Events API](http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html)

Comment: I've managed to hide the footer using an owl event (linked above), in this instance 'changed' `$("#cases").on('changed.owl.carousel',function () {
    $('footer').find('#select').css("display", "none");
  });` Though I only want to hide the footer when a certain item is shown. Any suggestions? @pravin-waychal

Comment: Fixed it :) http://jsfiddle.net/av0bkbzx/1/ `$("#cases").on('changed.owl.carousel',function(event) {
    if( event.item.index === 1 || event.item.index === 2 || event.item.index === 5 ) {
      $('footer').find('#select').css("display", "none");
    }
    else if( event.item.index === 0 || event.item.index === 3 || event.item.index === 4 ) {
      $('footer').find('#select').css("display", "block");
    }
  });`

Comment: Glad you find fixed it :) code could be possibly optimized as - http://jsfiddle.net/av0bkbzx/3/ happy coding :)

Comment: One thing I did realise, I don't need to .find('#select') anymore, because #select is an ID and unique ?? Correct?